# Vagrant machine with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.2 generates Internal Server Error

Tags: apache2, vagrant, php

Have configured vagrant Ubuntu 14.04 machine with virtual box.

I get the error (in browser)

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

And get the error (/var/log/apache2/error.log):

```
[Wed Apr 01 20:58:34.609309 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 24066:tid 3046103872] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.33.1:59777] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br/php5.fcgi" aborted: read failed
[Wed Apr 01 20:58:34.614694 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 24066:tid 3046103872] [client 192.168.33.1:59777] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br/php5.fcgi"
```

My virtual host is configured with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername circulocolaborativo.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#    ErrorLog "/home/vagrant/logs/error_log"

    <Directory /var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Allowoverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        Alias /php5.fcgi /var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br/php5.fcgi
        FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br/php5.fcgi -flush -host 127.0.0.1:5200 -idle-timeout 900

        AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
        Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5.fcgi

    <Location /var/www/html/circulocolaborativo.com.br/libraries/Sciere/ws/sptl >
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "WebService SPTL"
        AuthDigestDomain /libraries/Sciere/ws/sptl/

        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.digest_pw_sptl
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could someone help me to solve this issue? I can't figure out what is going on. I'm using php-fpm with fastcgi module.

Comment: What memory error? There's nothing about memory in your log snippets.

Comment: You vhost configuration seems bad. "Require all granted" is not a statement for Apache 2.2, it's an Apache 2.4 command. First of all you should review this configuration. Take some time to read through the differences between 2.2 and 2.4 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Comment: Sorry @P.R.Ribeiro, I have build a new machine Ubuntu 14.04, with Apache 2.4. The error is the same. Thanks.

Comment: The config still is not right. The commands "Order allow, deny / Allow from all" are for Apache 2.2.

Comment: Thanks again @P.R.Ribeiro, I've fixed too. Same problem.